# react-query refetches data on page change in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

I'm working on a project named goloop with serverless backend hosten on vercel.

The frontend ( nextjs ) uses react-query hooks to fetch data. As it is a e-commerce site i am fetching all the products on my landing page and show a skeleton component while it's fetching data.
The problem here is it refetch's the data every time when the page is changed which is kinda annyoing.

I am creating the client this way :

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: {
      queries: {
        retry: false,
        staleTime: 60 * 1000 * 5,
        onError: (e) => {
          if ("message" in (e as Error)) {
            console.log((e as Error).message);
          }
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

If you need any further code please inform me or checkout the repo : https://github.com/lorstenoplo/eccom-next

The app is hosted here : https://goloop.vercel.app

Comment: You have got the issue, i understood what you are telling but can you show a code example for how i would check and prevent api call

Comment: nvm i got another solution by creating a query client for every page

Comment: nah its acting weird again, i'll find a proper fix then post the answer

Comment: got any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

The easy fix is :

1. adding a stale time
2. Create a new queryCache and providing it in the client options
3. Most importantly restart your server and ide